# Is it nessesary to lock table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, deadlock

I have `users` table and `tasks` table with `user_id` column. There is requirement that user should have only one task in `active` status.

Basicly user can have many tasks in `todo`, `done` statuses, but only one task in `active` status.

The question is how do I update the task status to keep only one active task for user. (Possible situation that there will be 2 simultaneous update operations for different tasks and same user assigned to task)
My thoughts are:

1. start transaction
2. lock tasks table for update and insert
3. check if user have active task
4. if not update task status
5. unlock table
6. commit transaction

Is is the right approach?

Comment: you'd be better off posting code....

Comment: which db are you using

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph, postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better option to locking would be to define a conditional unique index.

You create the index entries on the userid when the status=Active

```
create index idx_userid on users(user_id)
where status='Active
```

Here is a simple example

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0df9c557f4e8ef659f02172b367d0ada

Comment: Having the constraints will ensure your model caters to multi user scenarios

Comment: Sql Server has something similar, though it looks little different, but I don't recall that MySql supports this -- at least in terms of a partial index (I could be wrong about that). Also, I add something about being prepared to handle the resulting INSERT/UPDATE fails in client code.